# opencart 2.1.0.2 currency and language dropdown not working

Tags: currency, dropdown

My drop-downs for language and currency have stopped working. The code is unchanged in the header.tpl file, but I may have accidentally altered something in another file. Does anyone know which file controls these two dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

currency.tpl & language.tpl template files controls currency & language dropdown respectivley.
Currency & Language files are located at **catalog/view/theme//template/common**

I hope this helps u. You can test some [OpenCart templates](http://www.magikcommerce.com/opencart/themes/)